# Connecting Doctrine 2 to MSSQL For SYMFONY 2 On Linux

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to use Doctrine 2 (for Symfony 2) to connect to MSSQLServer from a linux machine.

I have installed pdo_dblib (PDO Driver for FreeTDS/Sybase DB-lib) and am able to connect to the db server via tsql on the command line and from the php cli also. Thus I know this is working.

In my Symfony/app/config/parameters.ini file I had specified database_driver="pdo_sqlsrv" as the database driver (as I read that this would be handled by `db_lib`) but when trying to run a create database command (using the command `php app/console doctrine:database:create`) I am getting the error:

> Could not create database for connection named  could not find driver

I then changed the driver to `database_driver="pdo_dblib"` and I am now getting the error:

> [Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]
>   The given 'driver' pdo_dblib is unknown, Doctrine currently supports
>   only the following drivers: pdo_mysql, pdo_sqlite, pdo_pgsql, pdo_oci,
>   oci8, ibm_db2, pdo_ibm, pdo_sqlsrv

So it seems that to connect to MSSQL my only option is `pdo_sqlsrv`, so I went to install this. However, [I have just discovered here](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php), that

> The PDO_SQLSRV extension is only compatible with PHP running on Windows.

Thus the driver supported by doctrine and those available to use on linux seem to be mutually exlusive.  From searching I haven't found any instances of this issue being solved thus far (One guy marked the issue as solved, but when I read the thread he had simply moved his dev env to a windows box... not exactly what I had in mind!).

Comment: Please take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8492941/doctrine-2-how-to-add-custom-dbal-driver and leave a message if the non-accepted answer did help you.

Comment: Hi Hakre, Thanks for your response.

I've read your post, and understand what you are describing, but where did you get this class from?

driver_class: Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\MsSql\Driver

Did you have to manually copy it from somewhere?  As mentioned, I am using pdo_dblib.

Rob Ganly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Under linux (at least Debian based distros), php needs the package `php5-sybase` that brings support for Sybase and MSSql.

If you are using a debian based distribution you will want to do

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5-sybase
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

And

```
php -r "phpinfo();" | grep "PDO drivers"
```

should give you

> PDO drivers: dblib, mysql, sqlite, ...

`dblib` is actually the one we need

Now to be able to use this driver with Doctrine, this post:
[Doctrine 2 - How to add custom DBAL driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8492941/doctrine-2-how-to-add-custom-dbal-driver) helped me to find the answer.

The OP suggests to use this [bundle on git](https://github.com/intellectsoft-uk/MssqlBundle) that makes things work together.

Comment: Thanks Pierre, I found that post you mentioned on adding a custom DBAL driver.  I also got to the stage where I was getting the error mentioned in that post, i.e. "The given 'driver' pdo_dblib is unknown".  Seeing as it wasn't supported 'out of the box' by doctrine2 I was unsure if there would be problems further down the line if I did this modification, so decided that we didn't *need* to use MSSQL for the project. I used MySQL instead, and this proved unproblematic.  It seems like other people have that solution working though, so I'll accept your answer.  Thanks again! Rob Ganly

Comment: It's surely a better idea to use MySQL or Postgre. I actually had to use MSSQL as a alternate connector to read external data.

Comment: Yes it certainly makes more sense to use MySql with PHP and Doctrine 2/ Symfony 2, this was understood and considered before starting the project. However seeing as it meant going against the status quo of the development and production environments here I decided to puruse the MSSQL route.  However when these problems became evident a measured view was taken and this route abandoned.  Such is the life of a developer!  Works great with MySQL now though! Thanks for your input. :) Rob Ganly