# Connect Symfony2 to MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, symfony, doctrine-orm

I worked with Symfony2 using MySQL and now i'm asked to work with it using MS SQL Server. How can i procede? what should i add to the parameters.ini file ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

It might be that what I'm about to write reiterates something in the post @walid referenced, but by just quickly glancing at it I didn't see it...

First of all, when using MSSQL you need the [pdo_sqlsrv driver](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098). Just copy the version you need (PHP 5.3/5.4 nts/ts) into your PHP's `ext/` folder, add the extension to your php.ini and then restart apache. The archive contains both `pdo_sqlsrv*.dll` and `sqlsrv*.dll`, so make sure you use **pdo_***! You can check via `phpinfo()` if the extension was loaded successfully.

Your parameters.ini will stay pretty much the same, except for the database_driver, which obviously should be set to `pdo_sqlsrv`. It should not be necessary to specify a port in the parameters.ini but in case you want to, MSSQL's default port is 1433.

Just as an example, your parameters.ini should look something like this:

```
database_driver =   pdo_sqlsrv
database_host =     127.0.0.1
database_port =     1433
database_name =     Northwind
database_user =     DatabaseUser
database_password = DatabaseUserPassword
```

As a sidenote, I only use the yaml-config, so this might not be 100% correct!

Comment: This is only for Windows, for Linux php [suggests](http://php.net/manual/fr/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php#ref.pdo-sqlsrv.installation) the [ODBC driver](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28160) (that actually seems to be only for Redhat)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did with Linux (Debian):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11434909/305189

I basically installed `php5-sybase` and used it with [this bundle](https://github.com/intellectsoft-uk/MssqlBundle)