# Using MS SQL with Symfony 3

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, doctrine-orm, symfony

Hi there I need some help with Symfony 3 and a MS SQL Server:

I am using Symfony 3 and want to connect to a MS SQL Server, I've done some research and found out that it is not supported by default but there are some Bundles available to use.

After trying some of them I found one Bundle which partially worked for me (realestateconz/mssql-bundle) but I get an error Message everytime I try to query the DB (I formatted it to be more readable):

```
Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException: An exception occurred while executing 
'SELECT 
  t0.id AS id_1, 
  t0.username AS username_2
FROM user t0 
WHERE t0.username = ?' with params ["testusername"]:

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 156 General SQL Server error:
Check messages from the SQL Server [156] (severity 15) [(null)]
```

The codeline looks like this

```
$user = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->findBy(array('username' => $username));
```

My doctrine and symfony settings looks like this:

```
#config.yml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver_class: Realestate\MssqlBundle\Driver\PDODblib\Driver
        host:     "%database_host%"
        #port:    "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        #charset:  UTF8

#parameters.yml
parameters:
    database_host: myserver
    database_name: database     #without schema
    database_user: user
    database_password: pw
```

Port and Charset in config.yml are commented out because I found something here on stackoverflow about doctrine using MySQL when port and charset are defined (can't remember where exactly though).
In the parameters.yml I can not add the schema for the DB (full path to table "User" is database.web.[User]) because it will run in another Error.

The Webserver runs Ubuntu 16.04 with apache2, php5.6 (including the package php5-sybase) and I use freetds to connect to the MSSQL-Server (manually connecting works).

Here are my FreeTDS settings:

```
[MYSERVER]
host = myserveradress
port = 1433
tds version = 8.0
client charset = UTF-8
text size = 20971520
```

As far as I understood it, Doctrine generates the wrong SQL-Query from the single line of code (MySQL-Syntax instead of MSSQL-Syntax), so what can I do to fix this? Or is there another way of successfully connecting and querying a MSSQL-Server on Linux with Symfony 3?

Comment: Try the "pdo_sqlsrv driver" mentioned in this [pdo_sqlsrv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648266/connect-symfony2-to-ms-sql-server). It's probably easier to implement than the bundle you mention above.

Comment: There is one comment which says that the sqlsrv driver is only for Windows. However I am on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: I saw this link too: [Link](https://dunglas.fr/2014/01/connection-to-a-ms-sql-server-from-symfony-doctrine-on-mac-or-linux/). Wondering if you've tried the simple test mentioned there: `php bin/console doctrine:query:sql "SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE"`. Also verify you have all the Symfony requirements with `php bin/symfony_requirements`.

Comment: I tried the testing and checked all requirements, it show now errors and I used `SELECT * FROM [User]`, which worked. When I use my Bundle with a MySQL server and pdo_mysql it works. But I have to switch to MS SQL. As I aleady said I think that the SQL-Query which is generated by doctrine (I think) is wrong.

Comment: Where are you getting the above indicated logs from? Is it from "var/logs/prod.log"? You can also use the "web/app_dev.php" debug URL to help troubleshoot problems. You just add "app_dev.php" at the end of your URL. It might show you some more useful information...

Comment: This error is from the web profiler, using app_dev.php

Comment: @levanth: was this just a test or do you still use MsSQL with Symfony?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution myself, you need to give Doctrine the exact Table name for your Entities in the Syntax the SQL-Server uses.

For the annotation Format Symfony uses it would look like this:

```
/** Annotation for your Classfile
 * ExampleClass
 * 
 * @ORM\Table(name="[ExampleClass]") <-- Square Brackets for MSSQL
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
```

After Changing the Tablename to MSSQL Format everything worked as expected.