# How to connect properly symfony 3.3.x doctrine2 and sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, doctrine-orm, driver, php-5.6, symfony-3.3

I am working with `symfony 3.3.10`, `php5.6.31` and I tried several times to connect doctrine to SQL Server 2005 database. I already installed the driver to use `sqlsrv` and `pdo_sqlsrv`. Here are my config files:

**php.ini**

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
```

**symfony config.yml**

`driver: pdo_sqlsrv`
`host: server_addr`
`port: 1433`
`dbname: dbname`
`user: db_user`
`password: db_p@ssw0rd`

That is my config, now when I try to do something with doctrine it raises the following errors:

Using `pdo_sqlsrv` as driver

> [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]
>     SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]ODBC Driver 11 f
>     or SQL Server does not support connections to SQL Server 2000 or earlier ve
>     rsions.
>
> [PDOException]
>     SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]ODBC Driver 11 f
>     or SQL Server does not support connections to SQL Server 2000 or earlier ve
>     rsions.

Using sqlsrv as driver

> [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\SQLSrv\SQLSrvException]
>     SQLSTATE [IMSSP, -33]: Invalid value type for option Database was specified
>     .  String type was expected.

my `phpinfo()` has no problems and is detectig both `php_sqlsrv` and `php_pdo_sqlsrv`

Registered PHP Streams  php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, zip, `compress.zlib`, `compress.bzip2`, https, ftps, sqlsrv, phar

**PDO drivers**

```
mysql, odbc, pgsql, sqlite, sqlsrv
```

Thanks in advance and sorry for bad English.

My SQL Server version output is:

Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.3042.00 (Intel X86)   Feb  9 2007 22:47:07   Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition on Windows NT 6.0 (Build 6002: Service Pack 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35796495/symfony-connect-to-database-odbc-connection-on-php7) which makes a reference to this [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/releases). Now I am using the lastest version (5.1.1). After check the extension is working I just configure multiples entity managers and I can connect to the database and execute/fetch queries.

php.ini

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_ts.dll
```