# Cannot find driver pdo_sqlsrv

Tags: php, sql-server, iis, symfony

I am using Symfony 3.0, PHP 5.6.17 on Windows 7, with IIS 7.5 and a SQL Server Database (MSSQL).

Like a lot of people, I'm currently having the pdo_exception:

```
  [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException]
  An exception occured in driver: could not find driver



  [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]
  could not find driver



  [PDOException]
  could not find driver
```

However, I don't know how to trace the error. Here's what I have:

**PHP.ini** The two dll are properly named and located in the ext folder

```
;extension=php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
```

I tried activating and deactivating `php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll` without any difference.

It looks, from phpinfo that the files are loaded:

[image]

Also, doing `php -i` I can see that it is enabled in command line also:

[image]

Finally, here's what I have in Symfony's config file:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_sqlsrv
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
```

I really don't know what to look into anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in this code you notice :

```
;extension=php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
```

You must decomment first line :

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
```

Also :

- restart IIS
- app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata
- app/console doctrine:cache:clear-query
- app/console doctrine:cache:clear-result
- app/console cache:clear

Perhaps you can also read this : [Topic StackOverflow for Doctrine MSSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8492941/doctrine-2-how-to-add-custom-dbal-driver)

Comment: That did it! I Thanks a lot!